# The download intent collision when I have two android app similiar

Tags: java, android, android-intent, download

Recently I am working two app , say appA and appB, appB is almost the same of appA but only change the package name and path. I found a strange problem in using two app. The problem is, when I either install one of it, the next install one will stuck at the download. So I suspect it is cause by download service collision, but I still don't know where should I change.

DownloadService.java

```
 if (intent.getAction().equals("com.myApp.downloadmanager.services.IDownloadService")) {
                int type = intent.getIntExtra(MyIntents.TYPE, -1);
                String url;

                switch (type) {
                    case MyIntents.Types.START:
                        if (!mDownloadManager.isRunning()) {
                            mDownloadManager.startManage();
                        } else {
                            mDownloadManager.reBroadcastAddAllTask();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MyIntents.Types.ADD:
                        url = intent.getStringExtra(MyIntents.URL);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url) && !mDownloadManager.hasTask(url)) {
                            mDownloadManager.addTask(url);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MyIntents.Types.CONTINUE:
                        url = intent.getStringExtra(MyIntents.URL);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                            mDownloadManager.continueTask(url);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MyIntents.Types.DELETE:
                        url = intent.getStringExtra(MyIntents.URL);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                            mDownloadManager.deleteTask(url);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MyIntents.Types.PAUSE:
                        url = intent.getStringExtra(MyIntents.URL);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                            mDownloadManager.pauseTask(url);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MyIntents.Types.STOP:
                        mDownloadManager.close();
                        // mDownloadManager = null;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Downloader

```
public void startDownload() {
        if (Utils.url.size() > 0) {
            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(
                    "com.myApp.downloadmanager.services.IDownloadService");
            downloadIntent.putExtra(MyIntents.ACTIVITY_NAME, activityName);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(MyIntents.TYPE, MyIntents.Types.ADD);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(MyIntents.URL, Utils.url.get(0));
            mycontext.startService(downloadIntent);
        }
    }
```

I am wondering whether                  "**com.myApp.downloadmanager.services.IDownloadService**" will cause any collision if I run the app at same time? or other possible cause? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent service name is same cause this error. Just rename the service